# In bash I have overlapping quotation marks inmy code that doesn' allow for wrapping the whole thing quotes again

Tags: bash

I'm writing a small bash scrip and I would need this part in quotes but I can't do it because it will always have parts outside the quotes.

```
printf '%s\n' {a..z} | awk '{print NR}' |
xargs -I num -n 1 bash -c "printf '%s\n' {a..z} | awk 'NR==num'"
```

is there any way to either get rid of the apostrophes inside or get the whole block into quotes?

(sorry for my bad english and if I'm just being dumb about it it's because this would be my first ever full coding project)

Comment: I do not understand. Just `printf '%s\n' {a..z}`. `I would need this part in quotes` which part does "this part" refer to exactly? `it will always have parts outside the quotes` Which parts will always be outside of quotes? What do you mean by always?

Comment: please update the question with the (wrong) output generated by your script and the (correct) desired output; fwiw ... I ran your code and it generates, in a rather convoluted way, the letters `a` to `z` (one per line) and there are no quotes anywhere to be found in the output ... so, not sure what exactly it it you're looking to do ... ??

Comment: This really seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Stop trying to help us help you, and ask for for what you actually need. What is the actual end goal? (Not the obstacle to the step you are currently trying to solve.)

Answer (score 1):

Inside double quotes, you can escape other double quotes like so:

```
$ echo "a \"b\" c"
a "b" c
```

Therefore, you *could* write

```
"printf '%s\n' {a..z} | awk '{print NR}' | xargs -I num -n 1 bash -c \"printf '%s\n' {a..z} | awk 'NR==num'\""
```

However, this is probably not the way to go. The question is, *why* do you need this command in quotes? If you need deeply nested quotes, chances are your script is poorly written (for instance, it could rely on `eval`). Usually, you can improve your script so that you don't need deeply nested quotes anymore.